# Add Active class for multiple routes in Angular

Tags: html, css, angular, routerlinkactive

I have a side bar which has multiple option in it.I set **routerLinkActive** class to make particular option active when click but now if I go deeper or other route from that route,the active class is being removed.I wanted to stay one option active for multiple routes.
My HTML code is as per below.

```
 <div class="nav-list">
        <ul class="listing" >
             <li routerLinkActive="active"  [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true }" >
                <a  [routerLink]="['/']" (click)="disableOptions()" >
                    <i class="fas fa-archive"></i> Projects
                </a>
            </li>
            <li routerLinkActive="active"  [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{  exact: true }" [class.disabled]="isDisabled==true">
                <a [routerLink]="['/notebooks']" [style.pointer-events]="isDisabled ? 'none' : 'auto'" >
                    <i class="fas fa-book"></i> Notebooks
                </a>
            </li>
            <li routerLinkActive="active"  [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: true }" [class.disabled]="isDisabled==true" >
                <a [routerLink]="['/files']" [style.pointer-events]="isDisabled ? 'none' : 'auto'">
                    <i class="fas fa-file-alt"></i> Files
                </a>
            </li>
            <li routerLinkActive="active"  [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: true }" [class.disabled]="isDisabled==true">
                <a [routerLink]="['/screens']" [style.pointer-events]="isDisabled ? 'none' : 'auto'">
                    <i class="fas fa-desktop"></i>Screen
                </a>
            </li>
            <li routerLinkActive="active"  [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: true }" [class.disabled]="isDisabled==true">
                <a  [routerLink]="['/slides']" [style.pointer-events]="isDisabled ? 'none' : 'auto'">
                    <i class="fas fa-photo-video"></i> Slides
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>

    </div>
```

[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]

As you can see in first image the route is `['/']` so the active class working fine but in second image the route is `['project/create']` so that the active class is not showing.I want to keep active class for both routes .Please help me to solve this issue.Thank you

My route file is like this.

```
const routes: Routes = [{
    path: '',
    component: PagesComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGaurdService],
    children: [{
        path: '',
        component: ProjectListingComponent,

    }, {
        path: 'slides',
        component: ScreenListingComponent,

    }, {
        path: 'project',
        loadChildren: './multi-step-form/multistepform.module#MultistepformModule',
    }, {
        path: 'project/slide/create',
        component: AddEditScenarioComponent
    },
    {
      path: 'project/slide/edit',
      component: DragDropToolScenarioComponent
    },
    {
      path: 'notebooks',
      component: NotebookListingComponent
    },
    {
      path: 'screens',
      component: ScreenTableComponent
    },
    {
      path: 'files',
      component: FileListingComponent
    },
    {
      path: 'screens/create',
      component: ScreenCreateComponent
    },
    {
      path: 'files/create',
      component: FileCreateComponent
    },
    {
      path: 'notebook/create',
      component: NotebookCreateComponent
    }
]
}];
```

**['project/create']** is in multistepform component which has its own routing file.

Comment: The main issue is that you probably set the routes wrong. Route / never be the same as `/project/create`. So I think you should have a redirect to `/project` for the "default" url and the rest should work with `routerLinkActive` automatically.

Comment: @standby954 I added my rout file.Can you please check it now and suggest me solution according to that

Answer (score 2):

You can use nested routing for it. For example define your routes as

```
routes: Route[] = [
  { path: '', component: PagesComponent, children: [
    { path: 'project', component: ProjectComponent, children: [
      { path: 'slide/create', component: CreateProjectComponent }
    ]}
  ]}
];
```

And then you can have a `<router-outlet>` inside the **PagesComponent** and the **ProjectComponent**. The routerLinkActive will then react to the `project/**` route in the **PagesComponent** so it does not matter what follows. The routerLinkActive in the **ProjectComponent** will then be active for `project/slide/create` or whatever you route to. And I think you do not need the `routerLinkActiveOptions`.

Comment: Hi ,I added my route file code in question.can you please check that and suggest me solution

Comment: I've updated my answer, do you mind to create a stackblitz for it?

Comment: Thank you ngfelixl for your answer,actually I used routelinkActiveOptions because the ['/'] route option is always staying active .Because its a root route.I dont know other way to overcome that issue so that I used routerlinkActiveoption